# Haskell Pattern Matching for fuctions (+) (-) (/) (*)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

For a function definition, I need to output a error when division by zero is detected.

The general case is as follows, `op` takes the (+), (-), (*), (/) function.

```
liftIntOp :: (Int->Int->Int)->Val->Val->Val
liftIntOp op (IntVal a) (IntVal b) =IntVal $ op a b
```

The use case is

```
Main>liftIntOp (+) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 5)
Main>IntVal 8
```

However I try to detect the special case of division by 0. My solution is

```
liftIntOp :: (Int->Int->Int)->Val->Val->Val
liftIntOp (/) _ (IntVal 0) =ErrorVal "Division by 0"
liftIntOp op (IntVal a) (IntVal b) =IntVal $ op a b
```

But the first branch seems to match any operators.

```
Main> liftIntOp (-) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 0)
Main> ErrorVal "Division by 0"
Main> liftIntOp (+) (IntVal 3) (IntVal 0)
Main> ErrorVal "Division by 0"
```

I wonder how to single out the case for division.

Comment: You can *not* pattern match on functions, only on *data constructors*.

Comment: It would not make much sense anyway. What if I write `\x y -> (x + 1) + (y - 1)`, then this is equivalent to `\x y -> x + y`, but it is a different expression. Checking if two functions are equivalent is an undecidable problem

Comment: I see. So I need to detect it before calling the ```liftIntOp``` function? I do have a step that map a string "+" to the function (+) etc.

Comment: you can make a data type `data Operation = Add | Sub | Mul | Div`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your pattern match on `(/)` does not work, because GHC thinks you want to bind that argument to the name `(/)` and overwrite the usual binding of `(/)`. See this simpler example:

```hs
ghci> let foo (/) x y = x / y
ghci> foo (+) 1 2
3
```

As Willem Van Onsem noted in the comments, the usual way to deal with this is to introduce an enumeration data type of all the functions that you want to match against:

```hs
data Operation = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
```

Additionally you then need to give semantics (meaning) to those operations:

```hs
applyIntOp :: Operation -> Int -> Int -> Int
applyIntOp Add = (+)
applyIntOp Sub = (-)
applyIntOp Mul = (*)
applyIntOp Div = div -- note that (/) doesn't work on Int
```

Then you can define `liftIntOp` as:

```hs
liftIntOp :: Operation -> Val -> Val -> Val
liftIntOp Div _ (IntVal 0) = ErrorVal "Division by zero"
liftIntOp op (IntVal x) (IntVal y) = IntVal (applyIntOp op x y)
```

Comment: One minor issue with the example code, ```main.hs:13:24: error: parse error on input `)'
| applyIntOp Div = (`div`) -- note that (/) doesn't work on Int ``` . I could compile and run successfully after dropping the back quotation.

Comment: @HarryQ thanks, I should not have combined backticks and parentheses like that. It is fixed now.